# Wanted: simple physical representation of the influence of payload onto car tires

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

From measurements I can tell that weight, as a function of tire pressure increase, is not linear but more something like this:

[image]

50kg = 1 change in pressure

100kg = more than 2 changes in pressure, no matter how much that is at this point.

Also the change in pressure is higher for the front seats compared to the rear ones.

*Part of a possible explanation*: as said, the heavy engine does already influence the front tires more, so the same payload results in a higher pressure increase.

*Cons of this explanation* (or well maybe/probably the pressures just add up, and the part mentioned before has a higher influence): Of course also the position plays an important role. In the rear you sit much more directly on the rear tires while in the front seats you are pretty much in the middle between rear and front tires.

In the front, the pressure increase is better distributed. Lets say 500 total increase when I sit in the front left, then alone 200 are on the front left but also 200 are on the rear left. When I sit though in the back, more than 300 of the 500 is from the tire where I sit. A better distribution should be like 50kg here and 50 there and this results in a total increase of less than 100kg at one spot, looking at the curve.

$pV=nRT$ as far as I remember. I guess for the short time directly after someone enters the car we can assume the tire to be compressed adiabatically and of course the gas energy to be constant, so it simplifies to $p$~$1/V$.

But how do V and p(=F/A) change so that the measurements could be explained? (Measured with 0,03 millibar resolution)

Where does the form of the curve come from?

Of course I read this question's answers: [Does car tire pressure change with weight of car load?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132892/does-car-tire-pressure-change-with-weight-of-car-load) and it gave some nice insights. But here I have some empiric data which I cannot explain. For example different pressure change in rear/front seats but mainly where the curves form come from..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's one possible explanation. First, if you're graphing pressure vs payload, you should switch your axes--I was confused!

Anyway, the payload obviously is going to increase the pressure in your tires. However, your tires are also elastic. So, they can "stretch" a little, to increase their volume in response to a change in pressure. However, most elastic materials are harder to stretch the more they get stretched, e.g. a spring or rubber band. So the first time you add 50 kg, the tires stretch some to compensate for the increased pressure. The SECOND time you add 50 kg, the tires can't stretch as much, and so the pressure increases more.

Not sure how to test this explanation, though.

Comment: Woops, yeah that graph evolved historically. It also confuses me once in a while.. But I need it that way :D

I totally forgot to mention this. I had the same thoughts about the nonlinear "strechting"-curve. I just hoped someone could rate the influences of all this for a better understanding..